# How can i loop the observable sequence based on condition from each element?

Tags: c#, while-loop, system.reactive, observablecollection, observable

I have a sequence and i need to repeat it based on condition from each element. For example i need to reprocess an element if it's marked with a "failed" flag. My problem is i cannot find how to do the `while-loop` operation.

`TakeWhile` is almost what i need but it does not repeat itself.

```
/*
* The following lines are just an example to comprehend the idea
*/
var observableSequence = sequence.ToObservable();
observableSequence
    //This ´DoWhile´ did not worked because does not accept each element as argument
    //and sequence at this point is not the same as `observableSequence`
    .DoWhile(() => sequence.Any(item => !item.Failed))
    .Where(item => item.Failed == true) //OK here i could put another condition for limited retries...
    .Subscribe(item => {
        try{
            //Do stuff...
            //. . .
            item.Failed = false;
        } catch
        {
            item.Failed = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest merging the original sequence with a new observable that you feed objects into as they fail.

```
var retries = new ReplaySubject<Foo>();
var loopSequence = sequence.ToObservable().Merge(retries);

loopSequence
    .Where(item => item.Failed)
    .Subscribe(item =>
    {
        try{
            //Do stuff
            item.Failed = false;
        } catch
        {
            item.Failed = true;
        }
        retries.OnNext(item);
    });
```

It's generally considered bad practice to change state of objects in observables, so you might want to consider creating transforms instead:

```
loopSequence
    .Where(item => item.Failed)
    .Subscribe(item =>
    {
        try{
            //Do stuff
            retries.OnNext(new Item { ..., Failed = false });
        } catch
        {
            retries.OnNext(new Item { ..., Failed = true });
        }
    });
```

You should also be really careful with this pattern, since a continually-failing item will put your program execution into a kind of infinite loop.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  You could wrap the item up in a `Tuple<Foo, int>` and increment the `int` each time you pushed it through `retries` to track the number of attempts.  This would give you the ability to handle it differently after x attempts.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When i first wrote the code my first approach went to delete elements from the sequence and soon i realized that it did not worked... the only solution i though was to wrap the original object inside another one and add a "failed" flag. Your second code i cannot understand it well. How exactly transforms work (i mean where are they returned)?

Comment: @CodeArtist: Sorry, that code was wrong, and I fixed it now. The idea is that instead of changing the state of each Item, you create a new one with a different state. Also note that the only reason I'm adding a new item when things succeed is in case you need to subscribe to the results `where Failed == false`. If that's not something you need to do, you could avoid adding those into the retry subject at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each value and retry the operations independently:

```
observableSequence
  .SelectMany(item => 
    Observable.Return(item)
      .Select(x => //Do Stuff)
      //Optional argument, omitting retries infinitely until
      //success
      .Retry(3)
  )

  .Subscribe(item => {
    //Handle the results
  });
```

Optionally `Return` takes a `IScheduler` as its second argument which could change the order that retries get processed (recursive vs. trampoline).